# Cannot post question about tag on per-site meta, due to "quality standards" filter

Tags: discussion, bug

[In this simple post to the DSP SE meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/tag-called-canny-edge-detector), I was unable to post my simple and brief and relevant question to the meta page.  This response stood between me and posting it:

*"The question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar."*

This is totally bogus.  Why does this exist in Stack Exchange and what can be done about it?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title to your post. Calling things "bogus" attracts downvotes. Hopefully this more neutral title will make the question better received.

Comment: listen, @S.L.Barth, i get downvotes all the time here at SE meta. (how do you think i got from 101 to 43?)  still doesn't change what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

It lacks a certain... something.

If I were asking the question, I'd go with a title like "Can we update  the “canny-edge-detector" tag wiki?"

and have a body like

"I notice that the "canny-edge-detector" lacks a tag wiki and excerpt. While I'd love to update this tag, I'm not an expert in this field. Can we someone with the subject update the tag please?"

Now, there's a clear idea of what the question is from the tag. There's a good level of content, and politeness (tho one may argue noise) in the question. It clearly states what's needed, why it needs to be done by someone else, and asks for action.

Comment: it's cruft. (and i have to add cruft to this comment to get it to post).

Comment: There's such a thing as excessive information density. Its meta, and you're writing for people, not machines.

Comment: both things you say @JourneymanGeek are true.  and it supports my complaint. (the information density in my OP was just right and it was a damn machine that was insisting that i write to satisfy it, not people.)